# Best way to test hardcoded data

Tags: java, parsing, testing, junit

I have a  class, which parses data from html page and turns it into a collection of String. Basically I have a URL of online-shop and I want to have a list of its items.
My class have the following signature:

```
public static List<String> getShopItems()
```

usually method returns very large List (4k items or more).
My question is, how can I test this method? 
I think that I have to assert that returned list has correct size and contains all the items needed. But it would be very tedious to create List with 4k items and compare actual and expected  Lists. Furthermore, items can change in the future, and my test will fail.

To sum it up, I can get actual data from my method `getShopItems()`, but I have no idea how to get expected data for assertion in test.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're testing data extraction from a webpage, not the webpage itself. As a consequence, you can (and should) make your own test page. This way, you can

- reduce the list of needed items (I assume there aren't 4k different cases ?)
- ensure the data won't change

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, static methods like this are almost always a bad idea they make testing difficult.

Secondly, a `Resource` interface can really help testing cases like this. eg:

```
public interface Resource {
    InputStream getStream();
}
```

Then you could refactor the class to be something like:

```
public class ShopItemProvider {
    private final Resource resource;

    public ShopItemProvider(Resource resource) {
        this.resource = resource;
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getShopItems() {
        try (InputStream in = resource.getStream()) {
            return someFancyParseMethod(in);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, you've got the hook you need for testing. In a test case you can mock up an InputStream with just a few records in it, possibly sourcing a test file from the test classpath.

In production, the InputStream can come from a URL or File or maybe some production classpath resource.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to keep the expected items in a local file. Then you can load the file contents, store all items in a sorted list and compare it to the (sorted) list of your shop items.

Comment: If the lists have to be sorted depends on the test's intention, I think

Answer (score 0):

I normally split these tests up into 2 parts:

1. Testing the function thoroughly with basic / small data sets
2. Testing some basic properties with real data

You can achieve the different inputs by creating an extra parameter in the constructor (possibly optional), for example a location of a HTML file with test data. This allows you to inject fake data into the class.

## Basic Test

Try to get 100% code coverage with this test, test for error handling, and for invalid data. Use several data sets for this test, and verify all output is correct.

## Real data test

Try to use data from a real source, this could be the live site, but that might not always be available when running the test. Also it might fluctuate too much too write a proper unit test for. At least aim to write a test that will only fail if you have made an error writing the system (not if the data in the site changes). So most of the time I go for a data set that is saved earlier, so I can assert a bit more on the data set.

Now you have to be creative in your tests: try to assert for properties of the data. Examples could be (try to pick several!):

1. All prices in a price list must be positive.
2. There are no errors coming from your exhaustive error checking in the function.
3. Check the number of items. For the real data do this vaguely, for fake data do check the exact number.

Answer (score 0):

1. separate method that gets the data from the method that parse the data so you can test different inputs (parse method should take a string or a stream rather than an url)
2. do very detailed tests using custom, small inputs. this should be your main testing part
3. you can take a snapshot of the webpage, save it locally and use it to test real data. update this file when page structure changes
4. last part is integration tests. connect to real webpage and check if your parser doesn't throw exceptions, if it still gives some reasonable output (like a list greater than 1k elements), check if page structure didn't change. don't test for exact list content as the page may change. also don't include integration tests into your unit tests as sometimes page may be down, network may be down etc